# MySql how to show zero when no value found

Tags: mysql

I've got this query:

```
SELECT ent_video_tipo, count(ent_video_tipo) as cnt 
FROM entradas 
WHERE entradas.ent_user= '1' 
GROUP BY ent_video_tipo 
ORDER BY cnt DESC
```

And this will give me:

```
ent_video_tipo|cnt
       3      | 3
       1      | 3
       4      | 1
       2      | 1
```

when I do

```
SELECT ent_video_tipo, count(ent_video_tipo) as cnt 
FROM entradas 
WHERE entradas.ent_user= '2' 
GROUP BY ent_video_tipo 
ORDER BY cnt DESC
```

I get

```
ent_video_tipo|cnt
       1      | 4
       2      | 2
       3      | 2
```

And I wanted to receive a zero for the `ent_video_tipo = 4`. Like this

```
ent_video_tipo|cnt
       1      | 4
       2      | 2
       3      | 2
       4      | 0
```

`ent_video_tipo` has its own table:

```
type_id|type_name
   1   |    a
   2   |    b
   3   |    c
   4   |    d
```

Comment: probably you dont have any record related to the condition `WHERE entradas.ent_user= '2' ` for `ent_video_tipo = 4`.

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty i think he want to get the provided output. and being able to print '0' is his problem cause he don't have record.

Comment: yes and if you do not have the record it will be pretty difficult. It could be done with a union all but what if there are hundreds of ent_video_tipo different value ?

Comment: I edited the question to show the where `ent_video_tipo` gets it value

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok since ent_video_tipo has its own type you can use left join something as

```
SELECT 
evt.type_id, 
coalesce(count(e.ent_video_tipo),0) as cnt 
FROM ent_video_tipo evt
left join entradas e on e.ent_video_tipo = evt.type_id
AND e.ent_user= '2' 
GROUP BY evt.type_id 
ORDER BY cnt DESC ;
```

**[DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ee811/12)**

**UPDATE**  This is another way of doing it

```
select
evt.type_id,
coalesce(cnt,0) as cnt
from ent_video_tipo evt
left join
(
  select
  ent_video_tipo,
  count(ent_video_tipo) as cnt
  FROM entradas 
  WHERE ent_user= '2' 
  GROUP BY ent_video_tipo 
)e
on e.ent_video_tipo = evt.type_id
```

**[DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ee811/9)**

Comment: It stayed the same  :/

Comment: let me check give me a moment.

Comment: Ok I have updated the answer both the queries should work now, I would prefer the first one since the 2nd one will not use index on the joining condition.